# Is this the general equation of FLT that generates Pythagorean-triples?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let us try to derive the General equation of FLT for all powers as under:

If ac ,

```
  then (a+b)=(c+d) for all powers 'n'.

 Then the following equation can be derived as

        [ {c^n-(a^n+b^n)} + d^n] / (ab-cd) = z   ....Eqn -----A
```

- z , can be expressed as an algebraic sum that differs

  for each power in a unique way but consists of same

  number of terms for subsequent even&odd powers

  (say for 2&3;4&5;6&7....&so on )
- whereas,   z is also a positive integer for all powers.
- it may be proved that
- {c^n-(a^n+b^n)}/(ab-cd) < z       as well as
- d^n/(ab-cd) < z   for all powers in general.
- in other words, in general , for all powers n≥2
- {c^n-(a^n+b^n)} ≠ 0
- if we consider the values of 'z' for every power ,we get
- @n=2.       z = 2(a+b)^0(ab)^0(cd) ^0
- @n=3.      z = 3(a+b)(ab)^0(cd)^0
- @n=4       z = 4(a+b)^2 - 2(ab+cd)
- @n=5.      z = 5(a+b)^3 - 5(a+b)(ab+cd)
- let us say that (a+b)=t ; ab= v  &  cd = u  then
- @n=6.      z = 6 t^4 - 9 t^2 (v+u) + 2 (v^2 +vu +u^2)

  ```
   in the same way 'z' can be written for all powers and
   the general case of 'nth power in algebraic  sum of 
   ' m ' terms as
  ```
- m = n/2  (if 'n' is an even integer)
- m = (n-1)/2 ( if 'n' is an odd integer)
- it may be observed that  obviously in general

  ```
       d^n / (ab -cd ) < z
  ```

  - but it is equal to 2 ,the least value and a constant for
    all given three integers a

    way for Pythagorean- triples  &  proving FLT for n≥3
  - R H S  of  equation 'A'  can be written for nth power

    (p.s    involves double summation symbol for which 
               my knowledge of LaTeX is inadequate. I may
               try to furnish with the help of some research 
               student in my location)
  - whether this approach to the  theorem is acceptable ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulas_for_generating_Pythagorean_triples

Comment: @avid19;@mercio;@joel;@calculus. The question is actually about Pythagoras theorem as a corollary to general equation of FLT. please clear from put on hold

Comment: The question won't be reopened unless you clarify your post.

Answer (score 2):

I don't follow the body of your question, but to answer the question in the title:

Yes, there is, and the formula is:

$$(m^2-n^2, 2mn, m^2+n^2)$$

Comment: I have been trying to state the general equation for FLT and its unique behaviour  when n=2 to produce Pythagorean-triples

Comment: @wythagoras: This does not  produce all Pythagorean triples, for example it does not give $9,12,15$.

Comment: I don't claim it produces all of them.